# Handling multiple Get/Post method to the same view in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I basically have a view which has three columns like this

```
| Users | User's Profile |            Profile's Data
```

The first column list all the users and user's profile is like sub column of users, where the profiles created by the users will be shown. Something like this should come in the view when user 1 is clicked. And clicking the profile the respective profile data should be shown in the 3rd column.

```
| user 1 | User 1- Profile 1 | User 1- Profile 1's data
| user 2 | User 1- Profile 2 | User 1- Profile 1's data
| user 3 | User 1- Profile 3 | User 1- Profile 1's data
```

All these things should be on the same view. I have done showing the first users in the view. But not able to show the profiles of the respective user when the user(user 1 or user 2 etc.) is clicked. I use GET method to show 1st column(users) and GET method with id of the user to get all their profiles. I don't know how to pass all three group of data(user, user profiles and profile's data) to the same view. Here is what i tried but pretty confused how to carry on from this point.

Here is my route

```
Route::get('/candidates', [
    'uses' => 'candidateController@showClient',
    'middleware' => 'auth']);

Route::get('/candidates/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'candidateController@showProfile',
    'middleware' => 'auth']);
```

Here is my controller

```
public function showClient(){

   $client = new User();
   $client_details = $client
   ->where('role','client')
   ->get();

   return view('admin')->with('client_details',$client_details);

    }

   public function showProfile($id){

   $client = new User();
   $client_details = $client
   ->where('role','client')
   ->get();

   $profile = new Profile();
   $user_profiles = $profile
   ->where('user_id',$id)
   ->get();

   return view('admin')->with('client_details',$client_details)->with('user_profiles',$user_profiles);
    }
```

The second route works fine `Route::get(/candidates{id},..)`. how do i go about this ?

Comment: Its bit confusing actually. You have users, user profile and user data on the same view. When clicking on user's name, you are populating the profile column. Are you doing this with ajax? Or entire page loads?

Comment: I am not using ajax. I am reloading the page. I guess ajax should be the way to do this. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route file

```
Route::get('/candidates/{id?}', [
    'uses' => 'candidateController@showProfile',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

Here, by adding question mark on the id parameter makes it optional parameter.

```
public function showProfile($id = null) {

    $client_details = User::where('role', 'client')->get();

    if (!is_null($id)) {
        $profile_details = Profile::where('user_id', $id)->get();
    } else {
        $profile_details = [];
    }

    return view('admin', compact('client_details', 'profile_details'));
}
```

Now, on view, check whether profile details is empty, if so, then you have
show all clients page, else its show profile page.

Comment: Nope it didn't work , but i made small changes to your answer. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Route file

```
Route::get('/candidates', [
    'uses' => 'candidateController@showProfile',
    'middleware' => 'auth']);

Route::get('/candidates/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'candidateController@showProfile',
    'middleware' => 'auth']);
```

Here is the controller

```
public function showProfile($id = null){

$client = new User();
$client_details = $client
->where('role','client')
->get();

if (!is_null($id)) {
$profile = new Profile();
$user_profiles = $profile
->where('user_id',$id)
->get();
    }
else{
    $user_profiles = [];
    }

return view('admin')->with('client_details',$client_details)->with('user_profiles',$user_profiles);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any change to my answer. I showed easire way of handling things by cutting down one route call.

Comment: `{?id}` didn't make it to work optional , that's why i made it as two different route

Comment: You are supposed to put question mark at the end, like  {id?}. You mean to say it dint work?